# Mismatching android support library version

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic, and trying to compile an app using android-23, correctly specified in the config.xml:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" />
```

I'm using the plugin Cordova.plugin.diagnostic@3.3.3 (I need it in that version), and it gives me this error when I compile:

```
values-v24.xml:3: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: 
No resource found that matches the given name 
'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
```

As I searched, I noted that this problem was a mismatch of version of the SDK and the Support Library. Indeed, that is the problem. It is trying to build with a support library 24 (hence the error at 'values-v24').

To fix that, I had to manually change the file 'platform/android/project.properties' from this:

```
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:+
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+
```

To this:

```
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:23.+
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+
```

Another problem is that I cant download, by any means, the package 'Android Support Library rev 23' since it is obsolete, I have access only to the 'Android Support Repository rev 44'.

Change the plugin version is not an option.

My question is: **There is a way to change this behavior?** It is not handy to manually change that file every time.